# Best practice for sending unrelated data from server to client over WebSocket connection(s)

Tags: websocket

I am currently working on a single page web app that has a growing number of real-time widgets concurrently requiring different datasources. My question is which approach is best for using WebSockets as the vehicle for this data:

**Option 1:** The client opens a **single socket connection** with the server, then uses an API similar to the following to subscribe/unsubscribe/get/post data:

```
var socket = new WebSocket([URL]);
socket.emit("subscribe", [OPTIONS]);
socket.emit("unsubscribe", [OPTIONS]);
socket.emit("get", [OPTIONS]);
socket.emit("post", [OPTIONS])
```

**Option 2:** The client opens a socket for **every source of data it needs to run the widgets on the page**. Keep in mind that there could be many widgets requiring many different sources of data. For example, it would look something like this:

```
var sock1 = new WebSocket([URL]);
var widget1 = new Widget1(sock1);
var sock2 = new WebSocket([URL]);
var widget2 = new Widget2(sock2);
var sock3 = new WebSocket([URL]);
var widget3 = new Widget3(sock3);
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Andy